# Laravel IoC bind method

Tags: php, laravel, ioc-container

When binding an implementation for given Interface or Abstract class, e. g

```
$app->singleton(
    Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel::class,
    App\Http\Kernel::class
);
```

how laravel determines that given implementation is **one of** the implementations of the the passed interface/abstract class

Lets assume I have following interfaces

IVehicle.php

```
namespace App;

interface IVehicle {
    public function getNumberOfWheels();
}
```

IBicycle.php

```
namespace App;

interface IBicycle extends IVehicle {

}
```

I4Wheeler.php

```
namespace App;

interface I4Wheeler extends IVehicle {

}
```

Implementations:

Bike.php

```
namespace App;

class Bike implements IBicycle{

    public function getNumberOfWheels(){
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Car.php

```
namespace App;

class Car implements I4Wheeler{

    public function getNumberOfWheels(){
        return 4;
    }
}
```

Back to bind method :

```
$app->bind(
    App\IBicycle::class,
    App\Car::class
);
```

Give the above binding my question is how laravel validates OR not validate that Car is/or not is an implementation of `App\IBicycle`
interface ? What is the use of passing inteface/abstract class in more general sense if no validation is performed ?

Comment: I think what the Laravel IoC does is: "whenever you need an instance of A, return an instance of B" I don't know if if it internally checks "if B is instanceof A". Have you tried binding a class that does not implement the interface or it does not inherit the specified class?

Comment: Also, the main purpose of passing interface is code flexibility, hiding the details and dependencies of instantiating concrete implementations.

Comment: In all honesty, you could have just read the code behind `bind` method which explains clearly what's going on and why (there's a great comment block in `illuminate/container/Container.php`, line 167 - or search for `public function bind(`).

Comment: @Mjh , I have been through all Container code , and I did not get that so I am here . Please if you have understanding add answer with some code example , thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question well, I think you are looking for the Laravel [Service Providers](http://laravel.com/docs/master/providers). There is where you bind the implementation to an Interface. The IoC will look for those bindings (in your ServiceProviders) to determine which implementation it should use.